# Is there a way to prevent Shotwell from scanning a connected phone for photos?

Tags: 22.04, shotwell, photo-management

I use Shotwell for photo management on Ubuntu regularly and also tend to plug in my phone to charge off my laptop. Every time I do this, Shotwell attempts to scan the phone. Sometimes it does this successfully (taking quite a while to do so as there are a lot of photos on that device), and other times it locks up completely and has to be killed and restarted. Either way I sort of lose what I was doing, and this also spins up a considerable amount of CPU if I'm on battery power.

Is there a way to prevent Shotwell from doing anything with a detected phone? I'm okay with a command line option or (ideally) a menu option, but I've found no trace of either.

EDIT: Jumped into the support chat and talked to a helpful chap who pointed me at their ticketing system. Looks like this isn't enabled yet. https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/shotwell/-/issues/3 I will update if and when this gets traction!

Comment: Going a bit of a different route - do you ever transfer photos from your phone via USB? (Thinking that, if not, you set your phone to not allow transfers/not "trust" your PC and head off the problem at the system level?)

Comment: Yes, multiple times a week. Note that this is an iPhone and doesn't ask every time it connects on recent IOS re: trusting a computer. (I realize Android behaves differently, as I have one of those phones too.)